# QSA Rewrite Rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I was wondering if it was possible to the [QSA] function when rewriting URLS in WordPress.

I have this rewrite which works perfectly:

```
    function custom_another_rule() {
          add_rewrite_rule('^property-search/', 'index.php?page_id=29', 'top');
    }
```

I was wondering if it was possibly on that page to use URL variables I can pass to $_GET like;

```
http://myweb.com/property-search/?search=This+will+change&type=Bungalow
```

I've been looking everywhere I can find a QSA that works dynamically without having to manually set the attributes which is not what I want.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your example URL will work fine and you can grab whatever GET vars you need without modifying the rewrite. Internal rewrites don't work the same way as Apache's rewrite module.